# Is there a list or a document about init.d default scripts?

Tags: debian, sysvinit

From my understanding, `ls -l /etc/init.d` list all the scripts currently inside `init.d`, including those that was created later by user. If it's true, then I want to ask is there a document or list to watch the default scripts of `init.d`?

Comment: Default, as in on a newly installed Debian system? I presume packages installed by an admin may add new `init.d` scripts.

Comment: Yes. I intend to use that to compare and find if there is any malicious activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian, you can identify `/etc/init.d` scripts which have been added by the user with the following:

```
dpkg -S /etc/init.d/* | grep "no path found"
```

This will list the init scripts which aren’t provided by a package.

Figuring out whether an init script provided by a package has been changed is somewhat more complex. Debian packages ship checksums of most of their files, but not “conffiles” which include init scripts. So verifying whether an init script has been changed involves comparing the installed version with the version shipped in the package. For example, starting from `/etc/init.d/anacron`:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/init.d/anacron
anacron: /etc/init.d/anacron

$ cd $TMP

$ apt source anacron=2.3-24

$ cmp anacron-2.3/debian/init.d /etc/init.d/anacron
```

You might be interested in tools which flag modifications, such as Tripwire (`apt install tripwire`).

Comment: This is even better than what I intended to do. Thanks a lot!